# How to convert string to date type in the Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am try to convert string value to date. The string has this format : `yyyy-MM-dd`. But when I try to convert using select values (in meta-date I selected fildname, type = Date and currency = `dd/MM/yyyy` I got this error :

```
String : couldn't convert string [2017-01-30] to a date using format [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS] on offset location 4
```

If I do  in calculator step : Create a new field, Final_date as a Copy of field A; on Field A put the name of your input string; Data type is date and on Conversion mask choose the yyyy-MM-dd format (you don't have to pick one from the dropdown menu, you can write your own). I got the same error.

I am using the Pentaho Data Intagration 9.

I am try to convert the string format in `yyyy-MM-dd` to date type format in `dd/MM/yyyy`. For this case, how to convert string to date ?

Answer (score 5):

When converting from string to date you specify the **source** format that the string is using, so in this case yyyy-MM-dd. That should be in the format selection list, but you can also manually type in any format needed.

Once the field is in date format, it will be correctly output to most database types. For files, you can define the new format (dd/MM/yyyy) in the output step like Text File Output or Excel Writer. Alternatively, you convert the date back into a string with the desired format using Select Values.